# Momentjs UTC time is weird

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, momentjs

Im trying to send an api a asp.net UTC timestamp like this:

```
d = new Date()
test = moment(d).utc().valueOf()
test2 = moment(d).utc().format("ZZ")
utc_asp = "/Date("+test+test2+")/"
console.log utc_asp
>> /Date(1372670700799+0000)/
```

But the time the server gets is the same as local time?

Or this:

```
console.log moment(d)
console.log moment(d).utc()

D {_i: Mon Jul 01 2013 11:26:10 GMT+0200 (SAST), _f: undefined, _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _d: Mon Jul 01 2013 11:26:10 GMT+0200 (SAST)…}
 index.js:39
D {_i: Mon Jul 01 2013 11:26:10 GMT+0200 (SAST), _f: undefined, _l: undefined, _isUTC: true, _d: Mon Jul 01 2013 11:26:10 GMT+0200 (SAST)…}
```

doing this:

```
console.log moment(now).utc().hour()
>> 9 - This is correct! Its 11 - 2, but how come the above
```

Am I doing it incorrect?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Not able to grab a local timestamp, and convert it to UTC into javascript Date format.   Have you been able to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

To create a moment from the current date, just use `moment()` without any parameters.

```
var m = moment();  // returns a moment representing "now"
```

If you then want to format it with the MS proprietary `/Date()/` format, you can use:

```
m.format("/[Date](XSSS)/")
```

This will give you a value such as `/Date(1372728650261)/` which is suitable for passing to .Net and will ultimately give you a `DateTime` object where `.Kind` is `Utc`.

If you want the extended format with the offset, you can use this:

```
m.format("/[Date](XSSSZZ)/")
```

And it will give you back a value such as`/Date(1372728650261-0700)/`.  This matches the requirements of the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class in .Net.  See the section titled "DateTime Wire Format" in [these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx#sectionSection3).

However, I strongly recommend you do not use this latter format.  It's only recognized by `DataContractJsonSerializer` and the docs explicitly state that whatever offset you provide will be ignored - using the server's own offset instead.  That's rather silly, but that's what it does.  If you are using `JavaScriptSerializer` class, the offset is also ignored, but it has different behavior than DCJS (staying with UTC instead of going local).

For that matter, I would recommend abandoning this strange format completely.  Use the ISO8601 standard instead (example, `2013-07-01T18:38:29-07:00`).  This is easily done with momentjs and is the default format.

```
moment().format() // it's the default, no need to specify anything.
```

On the server side, use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), which also uses this format by default.  And if you actually care about the offset, use the `DateTimeOffset` type on the server instead of the `DateTime` type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try check if your asp.net Datetime use localtime, utc or unspecified for deserialization.